# JasperReports 5.0.0 - Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/javaflow/bytecode/Continuable

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with a project that use *JasperReports 5.0.0*. I deployed a war with the jasper's libraries in another servers and I had not any problem. But in the productive enviornment, when I want generate a report, the aplication throws the next exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/javaflow/bytecode/Continuable
```

The war contains the next jars:

```
jasperreports-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-aplet-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-font-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-5.0.0.jar
```

And the server is a *Weblogic 10.3.5.0*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: This class is from *commons-javaflow.jar*

Comment: JR 5.2.0 is using   <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-javaflow</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-javaflow</artifactId>
   <version>20060411</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency> artifact

Comment: Thanks for comments, but I have tried to add commons-javaflow to the shared library and I still having the same error. I  read that this error is throws in previous versions of Jasper and with comons-javaflow was solved, but aparently not with version 5.0

Comment: Did you add the *commons-javaflow-20060411.jar*? What version did you add to classpath?

Comment: Can you post your *Java* code to check this issue?

Comment: Sorry I can't post the Java code, because is protected by copyright. My team have added the commons-javaflow-20060411.jar, to the project that was deployed as a shared library.

Comment: And was added in weblogic.xml file, the reference to this shared library.

Comment: You can also check that is only one version of *commons-javaflow* library is in *OWL* classpath.

Comment: Alex, thaks for your help. Yesterday, we restarted the server and worked fine.