# Exception in Java with iReport 5.5.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I am currently creating a school project in Java using Netbeans.

And I am having problems with iReport 5.5.1

This is how I call my report within the program:

```
    String report = "G:\\AssessmentRecordSystem\\src\\assessmentrecordsystem\\reports\\report2.jrxml";
 try {
    JasperReport rep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rep, null, connect);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(print);
} 
catch (JRException ex) {
  //  Logger.getLogger(frmReportChooser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
}
```

The above code is called when a button is pressed. Then this comes out in the output window in Netbeans and nothing happens:

```
    2014-09-23 14:01:23,302 WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components`
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/javaflow/bytecode/Continuable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
    at assessmentrecordsystem.AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm.jButton2ActionPerformed(AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm.java:2166)
    at assessmentrecordsystem.AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm.access$1400(AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm.java:58)
    at assessmentrecordsystem.AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm$21.actionPerformed(AssessmentRecordSystemMainForm.java:1476)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.Continuable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 54 more`
```

And regarding about the imported jar files for the program. This is all the jar files I imported:

```
jasperreports-applet-4.6.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-4.6.0.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-4.6.0.jar
jasperreports-4.6.0.jar
groovy-all-1.7.5.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
devtools-1.1-all.jar
rs2xml.jar
```

Guys, i badly need your help and precious ideas about this problem of mine... 
Hoping any help will come in my way..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359568/jasperreports-5-0-0-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: No.. it's not. This is not a duplicate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `commons-javaflow-<version>.jar` into your Classpath

You can download [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.apache.commons/commons-javaflow/1209105)

Comment: i tried it and it worked with the report that is not using the Table Component in iReport, but with the table component it is not working..

Comment: This one: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException

Comment: Add jackson-all-1.9.0.jar into your classpath or just add jackson-core-asl-<version>